# Optimize function in Python using Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I have a dataframe `df` which has columns like:  `A` `B` `C`

I calculate mean squared error as :

```
alpha*df['A']*df['B'] is calculated value where alpha is unknown 
and df['A']*df['B'] are values from data-frame

df['C'] is actual value
I calculate the mean square of the value like:

MSE= 0.5*(sum(( alpha*df['A']*df['B'] - df['C'] )**2) )
```

I want to minimise the above MSE function to find out `alpha` which minimises this function and also the minimum value.

Can I use `scipy` library to minimise it over alpha on entire `R` domain

Currently I am just doing a grid search over some random alpha values to find all the MSE and then plot a graph to find minimum.

Thanks,

Comment: You can compute alpha in closed form by taking the first order condition.

Comment: hilberts_drinking_problem: can u show how to do it in pythonic way?

Comment: Should be something like `(df.A * df.B * df.C).sum() / ((df.A * df.B)**2).sum()`.

Comment: I am looking more into scipy based solutions.

Comment: You can definitely pose this as an optimization problem, but it seems a bit redundant when a solution is given by an explicit formula.

Comment: I can understand your point but from learning perspective can you show how to do it using scipy optimization.

Comment: Do you have an example dataset?

Comment: Yes and I have full code also,, it's just a demo